# How can a data-bind to an element within a Kendo-Knockout listview?

Tags: javascript, listview, mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a rather sophisticated template for Kendo ListView using knockout-kendo.js bindings.  It displays beautifully.  My problem is that I need to use the visible and click bindings in parts of the template, but I can't get them to work.  Below is a simplified version of my template.  Basically, deleteButtonVisible determines whether the close button can be seen, and removeComp removes the item from the array.

```
<div class='template'>
   <div >
      <div style='display:inline-block' data-bind='visible: deleteButtonVisible, event: {click: $parent.removeComp}'>
        <img  src='../../../Img/dialog_close.png'></img>
   </div>
   <div class='embolden'>#= type#</div><div class='label1'> #= marketArea# </div>
   <div class='label2'> #= address# </div>
   <!-- more of the same -->
</div>
```

The view model:

```
function CompViewModel() {
var self = this;
    self.compData = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo("compData");
    self.template = kendo.template(//template in here);
    self.removeComp = function (comp) {
        //do something here
    }
```

}

html:

```
   <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-12 centerouter" id="compDiv" >
            <div class="centerinner"  id="compListView" data-bind="kendoListView: {data: compData, template: template}"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

finally, sample data:

```
   {
         type: "Comparable",
         marketArea: "",
         address: "2327 Bristol St",
         deleteButtonVisible: true
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

Take in count that the deleteButtonVisible must be a property on the viewModel linked to the view.You are not doing that right now. The click element can v¡be access from the outer scope of the binding and remove the $parent.He take the method from the viewmodel. Take in count that every thing that you take on the vie must be present on the view model for a easy access.